# Ardor Conversational Wallet

Tags: ardor

Any idea what it would take to build a conversational wallet for basic interactions with Ardor accounts through a chat bot and what the potential risks are?

Will also appreciate any possible code repo dealing with this.

Thanks.

CryptAIVR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main challenge is how to secure user passphrases. 
In the past we had a slack bot implemented in C# https://github.com/libertyswede/NxtTipbot you can use it as reference implementation.